# GNUstep main file implementation

Tags: gnustep, objective-c

I'm not sure of the exact purpose of creating a main file that looks like this

```objective-c
#include "AppController.h"
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
   AppController *delegate;

   pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   delegate = [[AppController alloc] init];

   [NSApplication sharedApplication];
   [NSApp setDelegate: delegate];

   RELEASE(pool);
   return NSApplicationMain (argc, argv);
}
```

Over one that looks like this

```objective-c
#include <AppKit/NSApplication.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) 
{
   return NSApplicationMain (argc, argv);
}
```

Specifically having to do with the call to `sharedApplication:` and setting the delegate.

Is the only benefit to this that you can set the delegate ahead of time, would there be any other reason to use the first approach? Also do you need to set a delegate?

Comment: I apologize for that, I posted this when I was programming late at night and must have not realized that I posted it there instead. X-(

Answer (score 0):

GNUStep is not Cocoa. It has a lot of differences. For example, you may have noticed the RELEASE() function. In Cocoa there's a -release method instead.